# puzzled in one part of speech known as "adverb"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Difference between hard and hardly? Is hardly an adverb? [Duplicate]

Comment: _Hardly_ is a quantifier, a negative. _He hardly touched his food_ means that he ate very little of it, much less than normal or expected. _Hard_ is an adjective with two meanings -- 'solid' and 'difficult'. _Hard_ is also the adverb that goes with the 'difficult' sense: _He's taking it hard_.

Comment: There is another (pragmatic) usage, giving a comment on the unlikelihood of an event: 'He will hardly pay for a painting he knows to be fake.' 
                                                                        [modal adverbial at sentential level]